# Unable to deploy application to google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

When I press "deploy" in google app engine launcher I get this error:

> ... httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate
>   verify failed 2017-08-28 14:41:51 (Process exited with code 1)
>
> You can close this window now.

Windows XP SP3. App Engine SDK 1.9.56.

Comment: Try upgrading your Python to >= 2.7.13

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Platform team [does not intend to support Google App Engine Launcher anymore](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/5esgvujAqIQ). If you use the Eclipse IDE, you can install a App Engine plugin for Eclipse and use that to deploy. Or you can deploy [using Maven](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/gettingstarted/deploying-the-application). Or you can use the new Google [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/), specific docs page for deployment is [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy).